# Latitude and Longitude coordinates are incorrect coming from Firebase and identical for all posts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The location that a user retrieves from Firebase for a specific `post` is always coming back as the same erroneous location, always the same one. I have tried various alternatives for this code trying to work it around so that the specific location that user created for their event saved to the `GoogleMap` comes back, but keep getting same location for all posts and it's incorrect.

I've been using a few other posts with location problems on here, but haven't helped me.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1kg8.png)

**MapActivityUser.java**

```
public class MapsActivityUser extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_user);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("location")) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        double latitude = post.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = post.getLongitude();

                        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Event location"));
                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 10));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PostActivity.java**

```
    package com.e.events.Model;

public class Post {

    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String description;
    private String publisher;
    private String text_event;
    private String text_location;
    private String text_date_time;
    private Long timestamp;
    private MyLocation location;

    public Post(String description, String postId, String postImage, String publisher, Long timestamp,
                String text_event, String text_location, String text_date_time, MyLocation location) {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.description = description;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.text_event = text_event;
        this.text_location = text_location;
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public class MyLocation {

        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getText_event() {
        return text_event;
    }

    public void setText_event(String text_event) {
        this.text_event = text_event;
    }

    public String getText_location() {
        return text_location;
    }

    public void setText_location(String text_location) {
        this.text_location = text_location;
    }

    public String getText_date_time() {
        return text_date_time;
    }

    public void setText_date_time(String text_date_time) {
        this.text_date_time = text_date_time;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public MyLocation getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(MyLocation location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you save location to firebase? Did you save correct location? Check your database manually

Comment: Add the `Post` bean class.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman from my ```MapsActivityPublisher.java```.  So coordinates are saved to Firebase and then other user who wants to know event location clicks on TextView which takes him to the map that sets marker at event location. I posted a picture of what Firebase looks like. What can I do to fix it? Literally have no idea

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added ```PostActivity.java```

Comment: You mean **36.62** and **119.30** not coming?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman exactly man, not coming back correct coordinates. Instead I get a marker in the middle of Africa every time... And there is no event there... I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The "in the middle of Africa" would most likely be 0,0 - which would be default for a double.  See @Md.Asaduzzaman answer - meaning the `getvalue` is not finding all your fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set your model correctly. Update your **Post** like below:

**Post.java**:

```
public class Post {

    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String description;
    private String publisher;
    private String text_event;
    private String text_location;
    private String text_date_time;
    private Long timestamp;
    private MyLocation location;

    //getter-setter

}
```

**MyLocation.java**:

```
public class MyLocation {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;


    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

And then parse like

```
Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();
double longitude = post.getLocation().getLongitude();
```

Comment: I don't understand this part ```private MyLocation location;``` What is ```MyLocation``` is that variable type? Shouldn't it be double or something?

Comment: Check your database, there `latitude` and `longitude` isn't direct child of `Post`. It's a object named `location`. So you have to create an object to hold that data

Comment: Check my answer, I have created a class called **MyLocation** that holds the `latitude` and `longitude`

Comment: There is an error. In this code ```double latitude = post.getLocation().getLatitude();``` the ```getLatitude();``` is coming back red. Same happens for Longitude

Comment: Did you implement `MyLocation` and getter-setter of its property in your code?

Comment: Is that because of something I did wrong? Other than that I changed the Model class to reflect what you have above.

Comment: Yeah of course, I will post the updated Model class

Comment: Can you update post with latest data. Also check my **MyLocation** implementation

Comment: Just posted updated Model class... Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: Of course you did wrong. Create separate file for **MyLocation** and copy-paste my implementation there

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help man. It returns now the **Last** location of the place of the event that was saved to Firebase. But that is the location that comes up for all the events. For example, if I save Paris, Rome, and Berlin the only location Latitude and Longitude that I get for all posts is Berlin because it's the last one I saved. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: In that case need to check how do you save location to firebase. Please create another post with details

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey man I just posted the question you asked me to post several days ago. Do you mind helping me with it? It's in a separate post